# What is the duration for which Dwarka existed?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna

From the Mahabharata (Gandhari's curse), it is evident that Dwarka was submerged 36 years after the war but how many years prior to the war was it created ? I have gone through some online sources but none seem to speak of the timeline of the city as in how long the city existed for ?